# Istio: Ingress with host network

Tags: docker, kubernetes, istio

The `hostnetwork` configuration option of Deployment does not take effect, after pod started  the `80` and `443` port did not find

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: istio-ingress
  namespace: istio-system
  annotations:
    sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        istio: ingress
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/role: istio
      hostNetwork: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      serviceAccountName: istio-ingress-service-account
      containers:
      - name: istio-ingress
        image: reg.miz.so/istio/proxy_debug:0.2.4
        args:
        - proxy
        - ingress
        - -v
        - "2"
        - --discoveryAddress
        - istio-pilot:8080
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 443
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        volumeMounts:
        - name: istio-certs
          mountPath: /etc/certs
          readOnly: true
        - name: ingress-certs
          mountPath: /etc/istio/ingress-certs
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: istio-certs
        secret:
          secretName: istio.default
          optional: true
      - name: ingress-certs
        secret:
          secretName: istio-ingress-certs
          optional: true
```